# Searching a multi dimensional array for a maximum

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following array:

a) 3,7,2 // length x width x height

b) 6,3,9

c) 5,9,3

I need to perform a search to create a new list, compiled of the maximum value between the length and width for each variable. i.e. the correct **C#** code for this problem would return the following list:

a) 7

b) 6

c) 9

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Any suggestions?` Write code...

Comment: you need to find maximum of 2 first values of array?

Comment: I suggest you post your best try at your assignment and ask questions then.

Comment: Post a code how it is stored, it's 3 arrays of integers or 1 array of strings that need to be splitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<int> maxes = dimensions.Select(dim => Math.Max(dim[0], dim[1]));
```

or

```
IEnumerable<int> maxes = dimensions.Select(dim => dim.Take(2).Max());
```

Comment: I know this is an old feed now. But I managed to work it out. This is my solution: